# Find the element in virtually infinite list

Tags: python, algorithm, math, implementation

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> A list is initialized to `["Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard"]`, and then undergoes a series of operations. In each operation, the first element of the list is moved to the end of the list and duplicated. For example, in the first operation, the list becomes `["Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard", "Sheldon", "Sheldon"]` (with `"Sheldon"` being moved and duplicated); in the second operation, it becomes `["Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard", "Sheldon", "Sheldon", "Leonard", "Leonard"]` (with "Leonard" being moved and duplicated); etc. Given a positive integer *n*, find the string that is moved and duplicated in the *n*th operation. [paraphrased from https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/82/A]

I've written a working solution, but it's too slow when *n* is huge:

```
l = ['Sheldon','Leonard','Penny','Rajesh','Howard']
n = int(input()) # taking input from user to print the name of the person
                 # standing at that position

 for i in range(n):
    t = l.pop(0)
    l.append(t)
    l.append(t)

    #debug
    # print(l)

print(t)
```

How can I do this faster?

Comment: You can figure out the answer without actually generating the list. Doubling each name once will double the length of the list. You can figure out how many times you would need to double the list, and then deduce what the structure of the list would be at that point.

Comment: @khelwood could you please elaborate on that.

Comment: @Aman Are you looking for someone to solve this for you? khelwood gave you a huge hint that should help you if you want to solve it yourself.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am following khelwoods hint since then and trying to solve.. I am just a beginner thats why its taking time for me

Comment: @Aman Even as a not-beginner, solving problems takes time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that runs in `O(log(input/len(l)))` without doing any actual computation (no list operations):

```
l = ['Sheldon','Leonard','Penny','Rajesh','Howard']
n = int(input()) # taking input from user to print the name of the person
                 # standing at that position

i = 0
while n>(len(l)*2**i):
    n = n - len(l)* (2**i)
    i = i + 1

index = int((n-1)/(2**i ))

print(l[index])
```

Explanation: every time you push back the entire list, the list length will grow by  exactly `len(l) x 2^i`. But you have to first find out how many times this happens. This is what the while is doing (that's what `n = n - len(l)* (2**i)` is doing). The while stops when it realized that `i` times of appending the double list will happen. Finally, after you have figured `i` out, you have to compute the index. But in the `i`-th appeneded list, every element is copied `2^i` times, so you have to devide the number by `2**i`. One minor detail is that for the index you have to subtract by `1` because lists in Python are 0-indexed while your input is 1-indexed.

Answer (score 0):

As @khelwood said, you can deduce how many times you have to double the list.

To understand this, note that if you start with a list of 5 people and do 5 steps of your iteration, you will the same order as before just with everyone twice in it.

I am not 100% sure what you mean with the nth position as it shifts all the time, but if you mean the person in front after n iterations, solve for the largest integer i that fulfills

```
5*2^i<n
```

to get the number of times your list doubled. Then just look at the remaining list (each name is mentioned i times) to get the name at position n-5*2^i.

Answer (score -1):

You are not going to be able to avoid calculating the list, but maybe you can make it a bit easier:

Every cycle (When sheldon is first again) the length of the list has doubled, so it looks like this:

After 1 cycle:  SSLLPPRRHH

After 2 cycles: SSSSLLLLPPPPRRRRHHHH

...

while the number of cola's they drunk is 5*((2**n)-1) where the n is the number of cycles.

So you can calculate the state of the list at the closest ended cycle.
E.g.
Cola number 50:

5*((2**3)) = 40 means that after 40 cokes sheldon is next in line.

Then you can use the algorithm described in the task and get the last one in the line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I recommend you reading, how to answer the questions. That would certainly help

Comment: Note that your suggestion avoids calculating the entire list. You use some math to jump ahead as many cycles as you can.

Comment: I recommend you appreciate a much more efficient solution than yours. I know its not really written out but to be honest, reading your question almost gave me a stroke so dont talk about writing